# Analytic continuation of a series $\Psi(s)$?

Tags: contour-integration, analytic-number-theory, gamma-function, bessel-functions, analytic-continuation

In the [Digital Library of Mathematical Functions](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.34) they list some analytic continuations of modified Bessel functions.

I'm highly interested in the analytic continuation of this function:

$$ \Psi(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2\sqrt{ns}K_1(2\sqrt{ns}) $$

which converges for real $s>0.$

> Why am I interested in finding this analytic continuation?

Because: $$ \frac{1}{w\Gamma(w)^2}\mathcal{M}(\Psi)(w)=\zeta(w) $$

which converges for real $s>1,$ where $\zeta(w)$ is the Riemann zeta function, $\Gamma(w)$ is the Gamma function, and $\mathcal{M}$ is the Mellin transform of $\Psi.$

In this spirit I tried writing: $$ \Psi(s)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty} z\Gamma(z)^2\zeta(z)s^{-z}~dz$$

and examining the residues, but I have become quite stuck at this point. This integrand tends to $0$ rapidly enough when $z\to \infty.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation $\Psi(s) = \int_C z \Gamma(z)^2 \zeta(z) s^{-z} dz$ is correct. The inverse Mellin transform equation is about picking up the residues, there's nothing essential about using a straight-line contour. In fact, as you have probably noticed, a straight-line contour won't work for this function. Here's a graph of integrand $z \Gamma(z)^2 \zeta(z) s^{-z}$ for negative $s$
[image]
(This was generated by the very helpful complex plotter tool which [you can find here](https://samuelj.li/complex-function-plotter/#z*(z-1)!%5E2*zeta(z)*(-t)%5E(-z)%2F(2*pi*i)))

With this in mind, you can take a contour like the following[image]

I'll go back and check for any computational mistakes later, but you should get something like:

$$\frac{1}{s} + -\frac{1}{2} +\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{s^{n}}{n!^{2}}\left(\zeta(-n)\left(1+n\ln(s)-2n\psi(1+n)\right)-n\zeta'(-n)\right)$$

Comment: Please clarify the function you're plotting. Is it $\left|z\, \Gamma(z)^2\, \zeta(z)\right|$?

Comment: So what is the analytically continued $\Psi$? does it have a closed form?

Comment: @geocalc33 The analytic continuation is given by that series. It is an analytic function on the Riemann surface associated with the logarithm.

Comment: @Gary yes - my comment came before that series was added